# Buying REITS in your Healthcare HSA?

Tags: stocks, investing, hsa, reit

I have a healthcare HSA account through work and am trying to figure out an investing strategy that makes use of the triple tax advantages of an HSA, does grow a decent amount faster than inflation and also is fairly conservative.  I was thinking about investing in REITs with high dividends, as that is a fairly guaranteed rate of return and also the dividends are not taxed.  I've bought a few shares of stocks like WPC and IIPR that I heard about from The Motley Fool and so far its been going pretty well.

So my question is, is this a good HSA investing strategy?  Is there something I should be doing instead of this or in addition to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specific investing advice is off-topic, so we can't say whether it's a "good" strategy, but I'll point out a few objective facts:

- Dividends are not "growth" since the value of a REIT will drop by the value of the dividend. The dividend itself is not creating any value, just transferring value from the REIT to you. If you reinvest the dividend into the REIT the net effect will be zero (you'll own more shares of a smaller REIT).
- Tax-free investments are generally not preferred in tax-free accounts like Roth IRAs or HSAs since you *already* get tax-free growth (you don't get a "double" tax break).

Since you get the tax benefits of the HSA regardless of what you invest in, the choice should fit your preferred risk/reward mix. REITs can help diversify a portfolio, reducing risk, but taxes should not be a decision point.

Comment: Thanks!  I should have been more clear with my goals.  I was looking to get more cash flow so it can contribute to our liquid value for medical expenses with something that holds steady or grows a bit.  The dividends on some of these REITs are upwards of 7% while they are also growing in value, so that hits my criteria pretty well.